# How to convert csv(comma separated) or xlsx(excel) file to psv (pipe separated ) file through Robot Framework or python scripting

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I have a file which can be a csv file or xlsx file , how this file can be converted to PSV file through Robot framework or python scripting

Answer (score 3):

From a CSV file to "psv" file through direct Python scripting using the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rU') as infile, open('output.psv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    writer.writerows(reader)
```

From `.xlsx` file to "psv" using the [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) package:

```
import csv
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)        # assume that the data is in the first sheet
with open('output.psv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='|')
    for i in range(sheet.nrows):
        writer.writerow([cell.value for cell in sheet.row(i)])
```

Comment: Since the question is about using this from robot framework, you might want to include a bit about how to use this code as a keyword.

Comment: @BryanOakley : question is either robot framework or straight python. I don't know the former, but if you do pls add a comment or answer.

Comment: thanks , I have added the keyword implementing the above python code in Ride and it works